# Visual Studio 2015, no Resource Build Action

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to develop universal app, I need to mark my Asset Image As Resource but I can't find "Resource" Option in Build Action.

Is it not recommended now?? or it is a bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out that it is not because of the Visual Studio 2015 but because I'm working with Universal App, if I open WPF app it will show Resource.

As for reason I guess it just another limitation in Universal App.